# jQuery removechild / hide html element without page refresh

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, joomla

I am trying to customize a Joomla Quiz plugin like this:

- a quiz question displays in the description an image / text, but it should disappear after 5 seconds.
- I found a solution with Javascript for removechild or timer function to hide after 5 second, and it works properly.

**the problem:**

this Joomla quiz module is not refreshing the page per questions, because it works with Jquery and I don't have an initial loading point from the timer could count the 5 seconds.
(by the time you reach the question, the time expiries and disappear to early)

I cannot use a page reload, as the whole quiz would restart from first question.

is there any condition or solution with Jquery or Javascript to detect the content load only for that specific question?
(I mean some div or some conditional rule to fulfill before start counting)

I hope it is clear what I want to achieve :)

thanks in advance!

Comment: have you tried using if conditions?

Comment: If you are a Joomla uses, please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

You can check visibility of the element by checking it offset like that in javascript. From the moment element is visible just setTimeout.

**Javascript**

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", checkVisibility);

    function startCount(){alert('IsVisible')}

    function checkVisibility(){
        var div = document.getElementById('Element').offsetLeft
        if(div >0){
            setTimeout(startCount,5000)            
        }
    }
```

**jQuery**

```
if(  $("#Element").is(":visible") == true )
{  
     alert("Div is visible!!");        
}
```